# How to fix compiler issues while using Comparator.reversed()

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, java-stream

How you are supposed to sort a list of objects by field in Java 8? Natural order works fine but reverse order throws a compiler error stating that you can't call a non-static method from a static context. I'm guessing that the method in question is `reversed()` and not `getValue()`, even though IntelliJ highlights `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue` in red and not the other way around.

```
List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>> z = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   z.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, new Random().nextDouble()));
}

// works
z = z.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue)).collect(Collectors.toList());

// does not compile
z = z.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the compiler cannot infer the type in the second case because of chained methods. You should tell it explicitly what do you want. This should work:

```java
z = z.stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.<Map.Entry<Integer, Double>>comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Here's how I'd do that instead:

```java
z = z.stream()
     .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
z = z.stream()
     .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Double>comparingByValue().reversed())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Other than that, since you're modifying the initial variable, perhaps this would be even better:

```java
z.sort(Map.Entry.<Integer, Double>comparingByValue().reversed());
```

Comment: Or `Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())`, which doesn’t use chained methods, so type inference works.

Answer (score 0):

The following format worked for me:

```java
z = z.stream().sorted(Comparator.<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>>comparingDouble(entry -> entry.getValue()).reversed())
```

I am not sure why the compiler is not able to infer the type of `Comparator`. So in the above example I have explicitly mentioned the type.